# How do I rewrite these php hashing functions in WinJS?

Tags: windows, winjs

I am trying to recreate the following php functions in my Html5 + Javascript Windows application:

```
function ComputeHash($plaintext,$salt){
    $plainTextNSalt=$plaintext.$salt;
    $signatureData=hash("sha256",mb_convert_encoding($plainTextNSalt,"UTF-16LE"),true);
    $saltData=mb_convert_encoding($salt,"UTF-16LE");
    $tmpStr=$signatureData.$saltData;
    $hashWithSalt=base64_encode($signatureData.$saltData);
    return $hashWithSalt;
}


 function VerifyHash($plaintext,$goodHash){
    $rtnFlg=false;
    $hashWithSalt=base64_decode($goodHash);
    $salt=mb_convert_encoding(substr($hashWithSalt,32,strlen($hashWithSalt)),"UTF-8","UTF-16LE");
    $expectedHashStr=ComputeHash($plaintext,$salt);
    $rtnFlg=($goodHash==$expectedHashStr);
    return $rtnFlg;
}
```

If anyone can come up with the two equivalent WinJS Javascript functions I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Look at [Windows.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx). It will likely help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd have to replace a few different functions in there:

The hash algorithm is tricky since JS doesn't have those functions natively. You could use something like [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for that part I guess.

For the base64 encoding you can use `btoa()` and `atob()` - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript) for some info on that.

Now, the encoding of bytes to UTF-16LE is going to be the hardest part... I don't know a way to do that. If you have to support that you may need to do some digging. If, on the other hand, you can ignore that requirement or use something else then you could use something like below...

```
function computeHash(plaintext, salt){
    var plainTextNSalt = plaintext + salt;
    // note the lack of something to replace "mb_convert_encoding()" below...
    var signatureData = CryptoJS.SHA3(plainTextNSalt, { outputLength: 256 });
    return btoa(signatureData + salt);
}

function verifyHash(plaintext, goodHash){
    var hashWithSalt = atob(goodHash);
    // note the lack of something to replace "mb_convert_encoding()" below...
    var salt = hashWithSalt.substr(32, hashWithSalt.length);
    var expectedHashStr = computeHash(plaintext, salt);
    return (goodHash === expectedHashStr);
}
```